# Wix bootstrapper: Using Win-Forms or MFC based UI instead of Theme UI (xml based)

Tags: wix, bootstrapper, burn

While reading source code for [WiX Extended Bootstrapper Application](https://wixextba.codeplex.com/), I'm wondering if I want to replace this Theme manipulation (xml based) with Win-Forms or MFC based UI, do I have to modify/rewrite all that or I can simply use references of some library, just as in case of Managed Bootstrapper, where we are using BootstrapperCore.dll??

wixstdba is mainly integrated with XML based Themes which it is managing in different events: For Example in **CWixStandardBootstrapperApplication::OnCacheAcquireProgress()**, there are method calls like **ThemeSetTextControl()** or **ThemeSetProgressControl()**.

Is there any good guide/Tutorial/Example for using Win-Forms or MFC based UI?

Regards 
Farrukh

Answer (score 1):

Here is a project that uses a UI coded in WPF:

> https://wixwpf.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks Morten. I'm aware of this. And I've already developed a Managed Bootstrapper with WPF UI. But I'm curious to know if we can integrate MFC or Winforms: as this has no or very least pre-requisite. WPF needs .Net framework 4.